# How to highlight search string in HTML

Tags: html, cgi

I'm using CGI script to create a Telephone Directory(Web based):If I give "ashok" the results will be as shown below.But I want to highlight the string "ashok" in the results(In the HTML page).How Can I do that?

```
NAME    PHONE No.   CITY    STATE   ADDRESS
Ashok   0956-253545     Gangtok     Sikim   H.no:A-22/54,lalnagar near kurji road,PIN::600033
Ashok Singh     0992-765876     punjab  Punjab  H.no:B-33/7,yerrakonda,ambedkar road,Pin:800234
Ashok Singh Sai     0452-764876     Gorakhpur   Sikim   H.no:B-23/7,konda,Bapuji road,Pin:4500234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it depends how you have the data laid out.  If you have it as a table, set the cell's background colour, if not wrap the text to be highlighted in a `<span>` and set the background colour on that.  It will give an impression like Google's cached pages highlight search terms.

```
<span style="background-color: #0dd;">Ashok</span>
```

Comment: Actually in my question the results will be given in Table and my search can be like "s" or "a" which can match in name,city,state and Phone No.So If I give "a" as search item then it should highlight all a's in the results in first 4 fields.

Comment: @ILLUMINATI7590, highlight just the "a"s or the whole cells containing them?